# Changing permalinks and redirecting urls

Tags: redirect, tumblr

I'm moving a client from Tumblr > WordPress. I can't figure out how to make the new permalinks work.

Two issues:

1. The current Tumblr urls look like this:  http://blog.example.com/847336253/post-name
   But when I import the posts to WP, it chops off the end of the urls. I end up with just: http://blog.example.com/847336253/
   **So, question 1:**  Can I append a slug to the end of that number? I've found a handy script that will rewrite the urls for me, removing the numbers and leaving me just with /post-name. But I'd like to keep that number in there.
2. The url of the site is changing from http://blog.example.com to just http://example.com. 
   **So, question 2:** Can I accomplish a proper redirect with a 301 directive in my htaccess file?

Comment: 1. Settings > Permalinks 2. Yes

Comment: You should only keep to one question per post. More than one question per post is not allowed, and this falls into the "too broad" spectrum, which means that there is no way of properly answering your question in a few well structured sentences as there are to many possible answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you would need a rewrite plugin, as WordPress wouldn't be able to handle the numbers in that string otherwise (it would see every site as a 404 Not Found), as slugs can't contain slashes of any kind.

Ideally I think your best approach would be to set the post names without the digits (to make them human readable), and then use a plugin such as the [Redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) to forward requests to the old URL (with numbers) to the new one (you can set up a regex redirection here, so a simple rule to strip out just the numbers, or you can do one redirection per URL if you want to be extremely thorough).

As for the permanent 301 redirect for removing the blog sub domain, the plugin mentioned above can handle this as well. Manually editing the .htaccess file isn't advised as plugins or themes may issue a hard refresh which overwrites the content of that file.

Comment: This is exactly right. Redirection handles this perfectly. All I had to put in was: .*/post/\d+/(.*) > /$1 and it all forwards along exactly as expected.   Thanks so much for your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1** Set `%postname%` as your permalink.

**Answer 2** For the 301 redirection, put the following code in your `.htaccess` file and put it inside the root directory of blog.example.com

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go Inside wordpress admin panel -> permlinks and you can add `%postID%/%postname%` to the custom  permalink field and you should be good to go.

Comment: Not a bad thought, but that number in the Tumblr url isn't actually the post ID. The post IDs were assigned starting from 1 when the Tumblr content was imported, so those long numbers in the url don't mean anything.